# Cannot give a link in javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript

Inside a while row, when i fetch data from sql, i build a link to a product page, like the following:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo '<span class="list-group-item autocomplete_link" onclick="search_k_2('.$host.'/termek/'.$row['termek_id'].'/'.$row['termek_seo'].');">'.$row['termek_nev'].'</span>';
    }
```

What i want, is when i click a  item, i want to go to that link.

My search_k_2 function is this:

```
function search_k_2(link_)
{
    document.location = link_;
}
```

Now, it doesnt do nothing, i get a console syntax error. How should i give the url correct  in the onclick event?

**Update:**

If i write it like this, the /-s will be removed from the string.

```
echo '<span class="list-group-item autocomplete_link" onclick="search_k_2("'.$host.'/termek/'.$row['termek_id'].'/'.$row['termek_seo'].'");">'.$row['termek_nev'].'</span>';
```

Comment: it renders as `onclick="search_k_2(yourHost/termek/foo)"` Do you see the problem? Where are the quotes around the string?

Comment: I added an update to the post bottom.

Comment: Is the problem here in the PHP code or in the JavaScript code? If the problem is in JS can you please post the rendered HTML code. And a second question: Why not just render HTML links instead of using span elements and JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `template literal` `` to Concat the URL in your `onclick` function

Also, use double quotes instead of single quote for your `echo` statement.

**Working code:**

```
echo "<span class='list-group-item autocomplete_link' onclick='search_k_2(`".$host.'/termek/'.$row['termek_id'].'/'.$row['termek_seo']."`)'>".$host."</span>";
```